# How can I resolve 'no matching toolchains found for types' bazel error

Tags: bazel, istio

I'm trying to build istio-proxy 1.14.0, initial build failed as follows.

```
Error in fail: npm_install failed:  (npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
......
......
Could not fetch metadata for strip-ansi@6.0.1 FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

I am behind a proxy.  I tried various proxy settings, including none and disabling ssl certificate verification etc.

I made the following change to envoy.bazelrc.

```
-build --java_runtime_version=remotejdk_11
-build --tool_java_runtime_version=remotejdk_11
+build --java_runtime_version=localjdk_11
+build --tool_java_runtime_version=localjdk_11
```

But it now fails with the following.

```
no matching toolchains found for types @bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type
```

Is this the wrong path to go down?

Bazel 5.1.1 is required but I have also tried other versions.  I also have java-11-openjdk-devel installed.

I'm hoping someone can direct me to a solution.

### Update:

After taking onboard SG_Bazel's comment, build continues to fail for me so I must still be missing something or misunderstanding what needs to be done.

Using local with following changes.

envoy.bazelrc

```
-build --java_runtime_version=remotejdk_11
-build --tool_java_runtime_version=remotejdk_11
+build --java_runtime_version=localjdk_11
+build --tool_java_runtime_version=localjdk_11
```

WORKSPACE

```
+load("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:local_java_repository.bzl", "local_java_repository")
+
+local_java_repository(
+    name = "localjdk_11",
+    java_home = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk",
+    version = "11",
+)
```

I include the following with build.

```
--copt=-DENVOY_IGNORE_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI_ERROR=1 --verbose_failures --java_runtime_version=localjdk_11 --tool_java_runtime_version=localjdk_11
```

Using remote with following change.

WORKSPACE

```
+load("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_java_repository.bzl", "remote_java_repository")
+
+remote_java_repository(
+    name = "remotejdk_11",
+    exec_compatible_with = [
+        "@platforms//os:linux",
+        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
+    ],
+    sha256 = "b8e8a63b79bc312aa90f3558edbea59e71495ef1a9c340e38900dd28a1c579f3",
+    strip_prefix = "zulu11.50.19-ca-jdk11.0.12-linux_x64",
+    urls = [
+        "https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.50.19-ca-jdk11.0.12/zulu11.50.19-ca-jdk11.0.12-linux_x64.tar.gz",
+    ],
+    version = "11",
+)
```

I include the following with build.

```
--copt=-DENVOY_IGNORE_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI_ERROR=1 --verbose_failures --java_runtime_version=remotejdk_11 --tool_java_runtime_version=remotejdk_11
```

Maybe someone can advise what I might try next.

Comment: Can you try this workaround https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/14864#issuecomment-1059282084

Comment: Thank you.  Unsure how I missed this when searching.  Obviously I have to change as I'm using linux.  I'll include in main body above for clarity once concluded.

Comment: Unfortunately build still fails for me.  I have updated main body above with detail.